# pass userData from callback-begin to callback-end

Tags: c++, callback, c++14

How to appropriately cache ***userData*** that is generated from user's `callbackBegin()` and send it to user's `callbackEnd()`.

### Simple version  (No userData - [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3f9368fe8e11e5c))

I want to create a complex database that support callback.  For MCVE, let's say it is `MyArray`.

Here is a simple array class that supports callback but no ***userData***.

```
#include <iostream>
template<class Derived>class MyArray{           //library - I design it.
    public: void push_back(int s){
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->callbackBegin(s);
        //do something about array
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->callbackEnd(s);
    }
    //other fields / functions
};
class Callback : public MyArray<Callback>{      //user's class
    public: void callbackBegin(int s){
        std::cout<<"callbackBegin"<<std::endl;
    }
    public: void callbackEnd(int s){
        std::cout<<"callbackEnd"<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    Callback c;
    c.push_back(5); //print: callbackBegin callbackEnd
    return 0;
}
```

It works correctly.

The next step : I want to pass some ***userData*** from `Callback::callbackBegin()` to `Callback::callbackEnd()`.
For example, ***userData*** is a clock time when `Callback::callbackBegin()` is called.

### My poor solution (`void*& userdata` : [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51c602d33acf3977))

Here is my attempt to implement it :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>       
template<class Derived>class MyArray{
    public: void push_back(int s){
        void* userData=nullptr;                                 //#
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->callbackBegin(s,userData); //# ugly
        //do something about array
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->callbackEnd(s,userData);   //# ugly
    }
};
class Callback : public MyArray<Callback>{
    public: void callbackBegin(int s,void*& userData){          //# 
        userData=new clock_t(clock());                          //# danger
        std::cout<<"callbackBegin"<<std::endl;
    }
    public: void callbackEnd(int s,void*& userData){            //#
        clock_t* userDataTyped=static_cast<clock_t*>(userData);
        clock_t clock2=clock();
        clock_t different=clock2 - (*userDataTyped);
        std::cout<<"callbackEnd time(second)="
                 <<((float)different)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<std::endl;
        delete userDataTyped;                                   //# danger
    }
};
int main() {
    Callback c;
    c.push_back(5); //print: callbackBegin callbackEnd time(second)=8.5e-05
    return 0;
}
```

It also works correctly, but I believe it is a bad design (at various `#`) :-

- `new/delete` in 2 places : potential memory leaking.
  Strong pointer is preferred, but I don't know how to.
- `static_cast<clock_t*>(userData)` is code-smell, at least for me.
- (minor issue) an extra ugly parameter `void*&`

**Question:** What are design patterns / C++ magic to avoid such issues, while make `MyArray` concise, easy to use, maintainable (i.e. not much worse than the Simple version)?

**Other notes:**

- In real cases, <5% of user's callback classes need ***userData***.
  Thus, I feel very reluctant to add `void&*` as an extra parameter.
  **Clarify: (edited)** The minority cases usually need different types of ***userData*** e.g. `Callback1` need `clock_t`,  `Callback2` need `std::string`, etc.
- Proposed solution should restrain from using `std::function<>` or `virtual function`, because the performance is a major concern here.

Thank.

Comment: 1) Your base and derived classes are tightly coupled, where base has knowledge of derived, so you may want to consider redesign there 2) What is wrong with making userdata member of Derived?

Comment: @mnistic 1)  `MyArray` know only that `Derived` has 2 functions with a certain signature.  I think it is common pattern in callback, and I don't think callback is tightly coupled.  2) It will be `userData` per instance of Callback, not per call.  Multithreading will become impossible.  Anyway, it is a great idea that I never thought of.  Thank!

Comment: @cppBeginner anyone can use static to create one `userData` for all instances

Comment: @Nikita I think I need 1 instance of `userData` per 1 call `push_back()` rather than per 1 instance of `Callback` or 1 instance of program.  Sorry if it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass data through a `void` pointer is a good C solution but (IMHO) not a C++ (specially: not a C++11/c++14/C++17, with `auto` and `std::tuple`) good one.

So I suggest to return a value from `callbackBegin()` and pass the value as first argument to `callbackEnd(); something like

```
  auto r = static_cast<Derived*>(this)->callbackBegin(s);

  static_cast<Derived*>(this)->callbackEnd(r, s);
```

Observe (C++11 and newer magic) that using `auto` as type of the value returned by `callbackBegin()`, you can return different types from different `callbackBegin().

Bonus suggestion: be more generic in `MyArray::push_back()`: using variadic templates, there is no need of fix the number and the types of arguments received by `callbackBack()` and `callbackEnd()`.

Using variadic templates you can modify `push_back()` as follows

```
template <typename ... Args>
void push_back (Args const & ... args)
 {
   auto r = static_cast<Derived*>(this)->callbackBegin(args...);

   static_cast<Derived*>(this)->callbackEnd(r, args...);
 }
```

The following is a full working example with two different callback classes (with different number of arguments and different return types)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename derT>
struct myA
 {
   template <typename ... Args>
   void push_back (Args const & ... args)
    {
      auto r = static_cast<derT*>(this)->callbackBegin(args...);

      static_cast<derT*>(this)->callbackEnd(r, args...);
    }
 };

struct cb1 : public myA<cb1>
 {
   int callbackBegin (int s)
    { std::cout << "cb1 b" << std::endl; return s+5; }

   void callbackEnd (int r, int s)
    { std::cout << "cb1 e -" << r << ", " << s << std::endl; }
 };

struct cb2 : public myA<cb2>
 {
   std::tuple<std::string, int> callbackBegin (std::string const & name,
                                               int num)
    { std::cout << "cb2 b" << std::endl; return {name+";", num+1}; }

   void callbackEnd (std::tuple<std::string, int> const &,
                     std::string const & name, int num)
    { std::cout << "cb2 e -" << name << ", " << num << std::endl; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   cb1 c1;
   c1.push_back(5);

   cb2 c2;
   c2.push_back("string arg", 7);

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::any` would allow you to hold `clock_t` (or any other) object and do away with the void* pointers, however that's a C++17 concept and not yet widely available (although there are implementations such as `boost::any`).

In the meantime, your code may benefit from a little composition over inheritance, as array and callback are conceptually pretty different and don't seem to belong in the same inheritance hierarchy. So, preferring composition, the code might look something like:

```
template<class T> struct ICallback
{
    virtual void callbackBegin(int s, std::unique_ptr<T>& p) = 0;
    virtual void callbackEnd(int s, std::unique_ptr<T>& p) = 0;
};

template<class T> class MyArray
{
public: 
    MyArray(std::shared_ptr<ICallback<T>> cb) { callback = cb; }
    void push_back(int s)
    {
        callback->callbackBegin(s, usrDataPtr); 
        //do something about array
        callback->callbackEnd(s, usrDataPtr);
    }
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<ICallback<T>> callback;
    std::unique_ptr<T> usrDataPtr;
};

class ClockCallback : public ICallback<clock_t>
{
public: 
    void callbackBegin(int s, std::unique_ptr<clock_t>& c){          
        c = std::make_unique<clock_t>(clock());
        std::cout << "callbackBegin" << std::endl;
    }
    void callbackEnd(int s, std::unique_ptr<clock_t>& c){
        clock_t clock2 = clock();
        clock_t different = clock2 - (*c);
        std::cout << "callbackEnd time(second)="
            << ((float)different) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    }
};



int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<ClockCallback> c = std::make_shared<ClockCallback>();
    MyArray<clock_t> ma(c);
    ma.push_back(7);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a smart pointer to avoid manually deleting your userData

```
std::unique_ptr<clock_t> userData;
```

pass it as a reference to your callbacks

```
void callbackBegin(int s, std::unique_ptr<clock_t> &userData)
```

and initialize it this way

```
userData = std::make_unique<clock_t>(clock())
```

Comment: With this solution, `MyArray` must recognize a specific type that `Derived` used (`clock_t` in this case).  As a result of the hard-code, `MyArray` will become unusable for others user's callback (e.g. `Callback2`) that may want to use different type of `userData`.  Can it be alleviated?

Comment: You can add a class template typename like this `template<class Derived, class UserDataType>` and instanciate your unique_ptr like this `std::unique_ptr<UserDataType>`

Answer (score 0):

The C++ magic you're asking about is a known as a virtual method. Virtual method is one of the C++ native ways to implement the callback:

```
 class MyArray{
      public:
        void push_back(int s) {
            const auto userData = callbackBegin(s); //# beautiful
            //do something about array
            callbackEnd(s, userData);               //# beautiful
        }
      private:
        virtual clock_t callbackBegin(int) const = 0;
        virtual void callbackEnd(int, const clock_t&) const = 0;
    };
    class Callback : public MyArray{
        clock_t  callbackBegin(int s) const final {        
          std::cout<<"callbackBegin"<<std::endl;
          return clock(); //# safe
        }
        void callbackEnd(int s,const clock_t& userData) const final {            //#
           const auto different = clock() - userDataTyped;
           std::cout << "callbackEnd time(second)=";
           std::cout << different/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
          //# safe
       }
    };
```

Another way is to pass two callable objects to the MyArray ctor and using those objects in the push_back method. The callable objects shall store calls to the relevant class Callback methods. Use std::function to implement those callable objects.